# Maximum number of files in a ipa or apk

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, ipa

I built an IPA with 100000 files (1500mo). When i try to install on all my iPad, i have the error message E8000004 (Error Unknown).

Tested on:
* Ipad second and 3rd generation
* IOS 5 and 6

Do you know the maximum number of files that an ipa can contain ?

Comment: "the maximum number of files that can contain an ipa" - any files can contain an IPA - did you mean "the maximum number of files that an ipa can contain"?

Comment: .. is 100k files "realistic"? Anyway, applying a manual "binary search" can allow finding the number of files that triggers that error, if it is indeed such a case, in a relatively small number of steps. Next up: 50,000 files!

Comment: yes it is "that an ipa can contain", sorry for my spelling error...

Comment: It's a map application based on leaflet.js, with all the tiles on the ipad filesystem. The users can't use wifi and mobile network.

Comment: That doesn't mean they need to be different files! You could make larger tiles composed of the smaller ones and index into them, just as you would an array of words.

Answer (score 2):

I can't tell you what the limit on the number of files is. But I have a proposal how you could  implement your app.

Run an embedded HTTP Server on your iPad as part of your app, e.g. [CocoaHTTPServer](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaHTTPServer), and have it serve the tiles. The tiles themselves could be stored in a single ZIP file, which is never extracted. Instead, the HTTP server would extract single tiles on-the-fly when they are requested.

This approach doesn't require Wifi or mobile network access. And you can still use leaflet.js. Indeed, you hardly need to change your app except for adding the embedded HTTP server.